# how to add logos to following span tag in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

need add some logo images in the following span tag

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4">

         <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"><br></span><b>LARGEST WAREHOUSES</b></p>
         <h6>Transport provide best theme for lioeiusmod tempor dolor list</h6>

<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"><br></span><b>GOOD TRACKING SUPPORTS</b></p>
         <h6>Transport provide best theme for lioeiusmod tempor dolor list</h6>
</div>
</div>
```

I neeed add logos near this bootstrap defaults font images

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin">
```

I need external css file I have images folder also

Comment: can I use both id and class in one span

Comment: is this what you need ? https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/7ef8r3x1/3/

Comment: yes how can remove class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" and put only new image logo

Comment: actually I need remove glyphicon images and put my new images here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Make use of pseudo elements `::before` and `::after`

```css
.logo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.logo::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0%;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url('http://imagespng.com/Data/DownloadLogo/Success-Transparent.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p><span class="logo"><br></span><b>LARGEST WAREHOUSES</b></p>
    <h6>Transport provide best theme for lioeiusmod tempor dolor list</h6>

    <p><span class="logo"><br></span><b>GOOD TRACKING SUPPORTS</b></p>
    <h6>Transport provide best theme for lioeiusmod tempor dolor list</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Style Accordingly

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/7ef8r3x1/5/)

Comment: then how can I add another image here I mean 3 images

Comment: only print red square I need put image here I give image path as content:url('w1.png');

Comment: set is as background-image

Comment: then I have some problem how can I put different images to this span tag

Comment: apply different class to different span elements and change the background-image for ::after elements as required